# Getting exception: Segmentation fault (11) while showing a secondary form on Android 9

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, android-9.0-pie, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm using Delphi 10.3 to develop an Android application. The main form needs to show a login form based on data stored in an INI file. But, when I show the form, I get an exception:

> Exception class Segmentation fault (11).

I'm facing this problem only on Android 9 (Motorola E6s model). On other Android versions, it works fine.

Below I have mentioned the simple code:

Form1 (Main form):

```
Buttonclick; // After showing the main form
begin
  Form2.Show;
end;
```

Also tried with another code:

```
ShowEvent;// On show event
begin
  Form2.Show;
end;
```

Please help me, how can I fix this?

Comment: Android is like that. Your task now is to adjust the code so that it doesn't produce the SF11 on any of your devices.

Comment: Without seeing your code we have no idea why it fails. Please provide [mcve]

Comment: I have added more details and not any complicated code

Comment: I just wanted to assure you know that you can answer your own questions. If you have solved the problem please do write an answer.